# Transition out of animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

So I have a box `.box`. That repeats a spinning animation infinitely.

```
@keyframes spin {
  0% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

The animation is only applied when the box's second class name is running

```
.box.running {
  animation-name:spin;
```

The purpose of this is so that I can easily stop the animation via javascript. (by removing the second class name.)

I would like it to smoothly transition from wherever it is at in the animation, back to the normal rotation which right now is `0deg`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use javascript to create a new keyframe. Set the 0% to the current position, 100% to 0deg, and calculate how long the animation duration needs to be based on the difference between the two.

Comment: @Our_Benefactors Thanks! I've been looking into different methods to create keyframes on the fly, they all seem a bit robust though. Is this the only solution? I feel like there could be a simpler way to do this..

Comment: I have a solution, mainly CSS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to make it work using CSS. The JS allows us to switch class names that's all. You have to use two classes for the animation: one that will make the div spin (`.spin`) and the other one that will terminate the spin (`.end`).
Both use the same [`@keyframes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes), have the same speed and are linear.

- `.spin` has a duration of infinite
- `.end` has a duration of 0.5s

Basically when the JS script (when button is pressed) the class `.end` is added to the div therefore the `.spin`'s property [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) is overwritten by `.ends`'s allowing it to rotate the div back to it's original position.

```js
var a = function() {

  document.querySelector('.box').setAttribute('class', 'box spin end')

}

document.querySelector('#end').onclick = function() {
  a()
}
```

```css
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: purple;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

.spin {
  animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
}

.end {
  animation: spin 2s 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="box spin"></div>

<br>

<button id="end">STOP SPIN</button>
```

Also don't forget to set the property [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) of `.box` to `backwards`

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks!

Comment: @GageHendyYaBoy Awesome! I wasn't so sure it would work with just CSS, I'm glad it does.